# How do you split a single column in a dataframe into multiple ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column for dates and I want to divide it into different ranges *(2017-2018, 2018-2019, 2019-2020, 2020-2021)*. New to python coding so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

- 1. create a random pandas dataFrame

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime

year = np.random.choice(a=[2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021], size=100)
month = np.random.randint(low=1, high=12, size=100)
day = np.random.randint(low=1, high=20,size=100)

smalldata = pd.DataFrame({'year':year, 'month':month, 'day':day})
smalldata['mydate'] = smalldata.apply(lambda x: datetime(year=x['year'], month=x['month'], day=x['day']), axis=1)

smalldata
```

[image]

- 2. create a new function to split the date to datarange

```py
def cutyear(x):
    if x == 2017:
        yearrange = "2017-2018"
    elif x == 2018:
        yearrange = "2018-2019"
    elif x == 2019:
        yearrange = "2019-2020"
    elif x == 2020:
        yearrange = "2020-2021"
    else :
        yearrange = None
    
    return yearrange
```

or use a more easy function

```py
def cutyear2(x):
    yearrange = f"[{x}-{x+1}]"
    return yearrange
```

- 3. next. us apply function to generate a new column

```py
smalldata.apply(lambda x: cutyear(x['mydate'].year), axis=1)
```

or

```py
smalldata['mydate'].apply(lambda x: cutyear(x.year))
```

- 4. show the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You specified **overlapping** year ranges (2017-2018, 2018-2019 and so on),
so it is not clear, whether rows from year 2018 should be included in
the period *2017-2018* or *2018-2019*.

I think, your ranges should be **disjoint**, so they should be definded e.g.
as *2017-2018*, then *2019-2020* and so on.

Assume that your source DataFrame contains:

```
         Date  Income
0  2017-01-10   100.1
1  2017-02-11   100.2
2  2017-04-15   100.3
3  2017-07-22   100.4
4  2018-02-10   100.1
5  2018-05-11   100.2
6  2018-08-15   100.3
7  2018-12-22   100.4
8  2019-04-15   300.1
9  2019-08-22   300.1
10 2020-03-07   500.3
11 2020-09-07   500.3
12 2021-02-11   800.0
```

*Date* column is of *datetime* type.

To group it into 2-year periods and compute e.g. a sum of *Income* for
each such period, you can run:

```
result = df.groupby((df.Date.dt.year - 1) // 2 * 2 + 1).Income.sum()
```

The result is:

```
Date
2017     802.0
2019    1600.8
2021     800.0
Name: Income, dtype: float64
```

It is a *pandasonic* Series. *Date* (the left column) is here the name of
the index column, actually the starting year of the 2-year period.
The right column contains total income for the period in question.

## Alternative for overlapping year ranges

If you want e.g. row from year *2018* to be included in **both** periods
(*2017-2018* **and** *2018-2019*), proceed as follows:

1. Define a function to compute the total income for a range of years:

   ```
   def incomeFromRange(yr1, yr2):
       return df[df.Date.dt.year.between(yr1, yr2)].Income.sum()
   ```
2. Then generate the result as:

   ```
   result = pd.DataFrame([ [f'{yr}-{yr+1}', incomeFromRange(yr, yr+1)]
       for yr in range(df.Date.dt.year.min(), df.Date.dt.year.max()) ],
       columns=['Period', 'Income'])
   ```

This time the result (a *DataFrame*) is:

```
      Period  Income
0  2017-2018   802.0
1  2018-2019  1001.2
2  2019-2020  1600.8
3  2020-2021  1800.6
```